# Equivalent cURL in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, curl, vba

I have an API for my application which allows me to make cURL requests to it.
I need to implement this into VBA so my desktop database can fire CURL requests to my web app.

```
curl -i --user admin@admin.com:password -X PUT -d "test=testing" https://mywebsite.com/api
```

How can i implement this in Access VBA? Can i use WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 ?
Any examples?
Thanks
Adam,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved it now guys, works well.
For other peoples convenience.

```
TargetURL = "https://www.mysite.co.uk/app/api/v1/test"
Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HTTPReq.Option(4) = 13056 '
HTTPReq.Open "PUT", TargetURL, False
HTTPReq.SetCredentials "user", "password", 0
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTPReq.send ("test[status]=" & Forms!curl!Text0.Value & "&test2[status]=" & Text2.Value)
MsgBox (HTTPReq.responseText)
```

Comment: What is the significance of Option(4)? The [WinHttpRequest documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't specify.

Comment: I know it is 3 years ago, but I also wondered what this Option(4) is there fore and I found some useful information under this link http://johankanngard.net/2005/11/11/winhttprequest-com-object-options-constants/

Comment: According to the [WHR Option docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequestoption),  the 4 is the enumeration value "WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags".  If you convert the 13056 to hex, you get 0x3300, which if you look further down to the SslErrorIgnoreFlags description, you can see that this ignores all the errors.

Comment: Thank u a lot. I used a Get method, so I didn't use parameters, only url, but it worked just fine. Thank you again