# Excel VBA (How to pull down a live update row from bloomberg and keep the previous data in the current row and put the live data in the next row)

Tags: vba, excel

As per title, i'm trying to pull down the bloomberg Live data to the next row while maintaining the yesterday's data in that same row. I'm completely new in VBA, can anyone do guide me as to how can i achieve that?

Example:

Row 1 data: Date 3/10/2016

Row 2 data: Date 4/10/2016 (Live)

Then for tomorrow i need to make it as such:

Row 1 data: Date 3/10/2016

Row 2 data: Date 4/10/2016

Row 3 data: Date 5/10/2016 (Live)

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like [cURL in VBA/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063550/equivalent-curl-in-vba) and you can use that to communicate/getting info from bloomberg. With this information you can use VBA and string manipulation (or regular expression) to update your row as you want.